# GCP: query all instances on all projects with specific label

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, label, instance

I am looking for an automated solution in GCP to query every month ALL instances on ALL projects with a specific label; for example, "test".

I would like the result to be grouped by the project (ID or name)

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

Your question would benefit from describing what you've tried.

```sh
LABEL_KEY="test"

PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  gcloud compute instances list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --filter=labels=${LABEL_KEY} \
  --format="value(name)"
done
```

The problem with the above approach is that, if the Compute Engine service isn't enabled in a project, you'll be prompted to enable it (and you probably don't wish to do so).

So, you can check each `${PROJECT}` for the list of enabled services, filter by `compute.googleapis.com` and then, if it's not in the list, pass on that project:

```sh
SERVICE="compute.googleapis.com"

gcloud services list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="name.scope(services)=${SERVICE}" \
--format="value(name)"
```